Calculate CPI of multiple price indexes
I need to calculate the composite CPI of a basket of products. Each product is measured as its own standalone price index.
Note how 2016 = 100
        2014    2015    2016    2017     2018
Rubber  119.16  94.96   100     121.89   94.53
Alum.   116.41  103.77  100     122.66   131.44
Gold    101.43  92.93   100     100.7    101.67
Barley  135.47  102.52  100     103.94   106.7
Maize   121.18  106.67  100     97.09    103.32


Hi, can you show us your attempt? For self study questions like these we require user to show us an attempt at solving the problem before providing solution

I would just average it out by the year. As in: 118.73 (2014); 100.17 (2015); 100 (2016); 109.256 (2017); 107.532 (2018). But it can't be that simple, right.

You need some weights to calculate a composite price index.
